# How to add means to an existing column in R

Tags: r

I am manipulating a dataset but I can't make things right.

Here's an example for this, where `df` is the name of data frame.

```
year    ID   value
2013    1    10
2013    2    20
2013    3    10
2014    1    20
2014    2    20
2014    3    30
2015    1    20
2015    2    10
2015    3    30
```

So I tried to make another data frame `df1 <- aggregate(value ~ year, df, mean, rm.na=T)`

And made this data frame `df1`:

```
year    ID   value
2013    avg  13.3
2014    avg  23.3
2015    avg  20
```

But I want to add each mean by year into each row of `df`.

The expected form is:

```
year    ID   value
2013    1    10
2013    2    20
2013    3    10
2013    avg  13.3
2014    1    20
2014    2    20
2014    3    30
2014    avg  23.3
2015    1    20
2015    2    10
2015    3    30
2015    avg  20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `data.table` where we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'year', get the '`mean` of 'value' and 'ID' as 'avg', then use `rbindlist` to rbind both the datasets and `order` by 'year'

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(setDT(df), df[, .(ID = 'avg', value = mean(value)), year]))[order(year)]
#    year  ID    value
# 1: 2013   1 10.00000
# 2: 2013   2 20.00000
# 3: 2013   3 10.00000
# 4: 2013 avg 13.33333
# 5: 2014   1 20.00000
# 6: 2014   2 20.00000
# 7: 2014   3 30.00000
# 8: 2014 avg 23.33333
# 9: 2015   1 20.00000
#10: 2015   2 10.00000
#11: 2015   3 30.00000
#12: 2015 avg 20.00000
```

---

Or using the OP's method, `rbind` both the datasets and then `order`

```
df2 <- rbind(df, transform(df1, ID = 'avg'))
df2 <- df2[order(df2$year),]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was really helpful:)